# Tampermonkey script to hide New Contributor Indicator

Tags: script, tampermonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Contributor indicator cutter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @author       Suvitruf
// @match        *://*/questions/*
// @match        *://*/review/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';

    var doc             = document;
    var newNode         = doc.createElement ('style');
    newNode.textContent = '.new-contributor-indicator {display: none;}';

    var targ            = doc.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || doc.body || doc.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (newNode);
})();
```

Comment: I find it entertaining that there's a 'new contributor' indicator on this post to help people hide the 'new contributor' indicator.

Answer (score 4):

I created a "knockoff" version to your one, which can be updated through [Github](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/userscripts/blob/master/hidenci.user.js) as needed (It's also a bit shorter).

## [Install](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WELZ-gh/userscripts/master/hidenci.user.js)